# -7713 reserved error in MsAccess

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2007

**ODBC Database**

When I get data using pass-through query in MS Access.
first time get data successfully. but second time get error  " **(-7713) Reserved Error** ".

I Don't Know Which Type of error and what are the reason error generated?

Comment: What SQL, pass-through to which database, where is the code? You need to add a lot more information.

Comment: I found Answer, please go this link: http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/ErrorNumberAccess2007.pdf